# Return Optional value with ?: operator

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17

I often need to use optional type for functions:

```
std::optional<int32_t> get(const std::string& field)
{
    auto it = map.find(field);
    if (it != map.end()) return it->second;
    return {};
}
```

Is there a way to return optional value in one line? e.g. this:

```
std::optional<int32_t> get(const std::string& field)
{
    auto it = map.find(field);
    return it != map.end() ? it->second : {};
}
```

results in the error

```
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
return it != map.end() ? it->second : {};
                                      ^
```

Comment: @tobi303 `{}` was not parsed as an expression.

Comment: Clang gives a much nicer error message: "initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator '?'"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can explicitly wrap the some-value return into an `std::optional`, and fall back on the `constexpr` `std::nullopt` for the no-value return.

> **[`std::nullopt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt):**
>
> `std::nullopt` is a constant of type `std::nullopt_t` that is used to
>   indicate optional type with uninitialized state.
>
> ...
>
> **[`std::nullopt_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t):**
>
> `std::nullopt_t` is an empty class type used to indicate optional type
>   with uninitialized state. In particular, `std::optional` has a
>   constructor with `nullopt_t` as a single argument, which creates an
>   optional that does not contain a value.

With this approach, the true clause of the ternary operator call explicitly returns an `std::optional` with a some-value, so the compiler can deduce the template parameter/wrapped type (in this example: `int32_t`) from the type of the supplied wrapped value, meaning you needn't specify it explicitly.

Applied to your example:

```
return it != map.end() ? std::optional(it->second) : std::nullopt;

// alternatively
return it != map.end() ? std::make_optional(it->second) : std::nullopt;
```

Answer (score 25):

```
return it != map.end() ? it->second : std::optional<int32_t>{};
```

should do the trick.

The compiler must deduce the result type of the ternary expression from the last two operands, but there is no way it can deduce `std::optional<int32_t>` from `int32_t` and `{}`.

`int32_t` and `std::optional<int32_t>` on the other hand do have the desired common type `std::optional<int32_t>`.

---

Related fun fact: You can avoid repeating the type with auto return type deduction:

```
auto get(const std::string& field)
{
    auto it = map.find(field);
    return it != map.end() ? it->second : std::optional<int32_t>{};
}
```

Depending on preference, you can of course also infer the template argument for the `std::optional` from `it->second` with `decltype` to further reduce repetition.

Comment: Depending on how `map` is declared (and the extent to which `int32_t` could plausibly vary at compile time), you could go even further and template it away.