# How to assign "nothing" to std::optional<T>?

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17

Reading about [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), I'm confused about what is the standard way to assign a value of *something* and *nothing* to an `optional`.

I guess `operator=` would be the standard mechanism to assign a value to an optional. Seems to work. Does this imply a copy of the underlying object?

What is the standard method to assign *nothing*? I've seen `x = {}` (which makes no sense to me as `{}` is an empty block) and `x = std::nullopt`.

Comment: [`myOptional.reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/reset)?

Comment: Braced initializers are allowed in several places across the language: `foo({x, y})`, `return {x, y}`, `p = {x, y}` ... In general, `x = {}` is a way to assign a value-initialized object to `x`. I'd say none of the three methods mentioned is "the standard method".

Comment: `std::optional` shares operations with other library types (`reset()` like `std::unique_ptr` for instance). And their semantics are fairly the same. I imagine it's to allow for optional's use in more generic ways (templated code). All those methods are "standard".

Comment: Not a direct answer but probably interesting for you (when wondering about different ways to assign to `std::optional`): Roland Bock gave a 5-min talk at CppCon 2017 with the title ["Making optional optional"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QB0oY5f6q-E). At the end of the talk he proposes an elegant way how `std::optional` could be used (after telling the story how he arrived there). Basically he proposes the ternary operator to combine `std::optional` and `std::nullopt` in this way: `map.count(key) ? std::optional{map.at(key)} : std::nullopt`.

Comment: Q&A somewhat related to @Julius comment: [Return Optional value with ?: operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45389872).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is one "standard" way to assign nothing to std::optional.

If you read [the proposal](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3672.html#rationale.reset_syntaxl) for `std::optional` ("A proposal to add a utility class to represent optional objects") the authors present two ways, in this order:

> We put the extra requirements in the standardese to make sure that the following syntax works for resetting the optional:

```
op = {};
```

> We consider that this will become a common idiom for resetting (putting into default-constructed state) values in C++
>
> Note that it is not the only way to disengage an optional object. You can also use:

```
op = std::nullopt;
```

`std::optional::reset` did not exist at the time of writing that proposal, so it was not mentioned, however it is also a valid way to do it.

Answer (score 15):

This is a choose your own adventure. You have three options:

1. [`my_opt.reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/reset). Just directly set the optional to a disengaged state.
2. `my_opt = std::nullopt;` This uses [`operator=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D) overload #1
3. `my_opt = {};` This uses [`operator=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D) overload #3.

Yes, (3) uses the `optional`'s move assignment operator (a default-constructed `optional` is disengaged, so this does the right thing). This is because `{}` will not match the [`std::nullopt_t` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t), and the perfect-forward assignment (overload #4) would be less preferred in the case where `T` is constructible from `{}` because it's a template.

(1) and (2) always work, regardless of `T`. (3) only works if `T` is move assignable, because we're going through the assignment operator. But (3) is the shortest. So YMMV.

If (3) makes no sense to you, that's fine, don't use it. Braced-init-lists are a particularly odd part of the language, and you can't go wrong with `reset()` or assigning to `nullopt`.